# pubsub push in s spring boot application with authentication enabled

Tags: spring, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create an endpoint in my spring boot application to be invoked by a pubsub message.

The application already has some security enabled for the users logged in via firebase.
The security config looks like this

```
http
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .anonymous(anon -> anon.authorities("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"))
              
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers("/pubsub").permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2)-> oauth2.jwt(c-> c.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customizer)));
```

the problem I am facing is that, even though I left `pubsub` endpoint out of security, spring still tries to validate the jwt, which is fine on its own, but it fails, which is the problem.

```
2023-11-21T12:48:01.964-05:00 DEBUG 52865 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
```

The JWT is obviously valid, and I can check it myself.

I think the problem is how I configured spring boot to validate the jwt which is by this line in config

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken%40system.gserviceaccount.com
```

Any idea how can I consolidate these two jwt tokens validation?

Comment: `auth.requestMatchers("/pbusub").permitAll()` this is for `/pbusub` and not `/pubsub` as you stated. Also `permitAll` doesn't leave out authentication.  The validation is a debug message, so should not interfere with the flow and will result in an anonymous access. My guess is that you made a typo in the url (as mentioned) and that hte regular config applies, leading to a 403 (because you aren't authenticated).

Comment: I changed the url for the post. There is no typo in the code unfortunately. And after the JWT validation fails, it just returns a 403

Comment: Let's try to debug to `JwtAuthenticationProvider` and see what happened with `jwtDecoder.decode(bearer.getToken());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer to this after some eight hours of trying.

I was way off, so apparently in the setup in the post, even though I tell spring not to bother authenticating requests on `pubsub`, if it sees a `authentication` header it tries to verify and validate it. Which is pointless to start with, and I consider it a bug.

So in order to make this work, you need two security filter chains, one for this endpoint, with disabled security, the other for the rest of stuff. The ordering of these beans are very important of course. The filter chain for this specific thing looks like this:

```
 @Bean
    @Order(-1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers("/pubsub").permitAll())
                .securityMatchers((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers("/pubsub"));
        return http.build();
    }
```

I made this `order(-1)` so that it applies first. The second one if you create will secure the rest of the endpoints.

The thing to note here, which really confused me is that even though inside the chain, I have a request matcher, Spring doesn't understand how to match the whole chain against incoming filter, that is why you need to tell it which URLs are assigned to which filter chain. This is done by this line

```
                .securityMatchers((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers("/pubsub"));
```

Looking at this, spring limits the scope of this filter chain to `/pubsub` and uses the other filter to secure the rest of the endpoints.